# Configuring users for JMS queue

Tags: java, glassfish, jms

Recently we set up a JMS queue on glassfish server so that people from remote machines can get some data from it.
We established connection, but we have a problem now.

There will be a lot of users, and we need to use JMS. How does one create a list of users (username+password) so that only those who are authorised can read from queue? Is this even possible?